# Second standard conversion sequence of user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I have a misunderstanding about standard-conversion sequence terms. I have come across the following quote [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) §8.5.3/5 [dcl.init.ref]:

> — If the initializer expression
>
> > — is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or
> >     function lvalue and “*cv1* T1” is reference-compatible with “*cv2*
> >     T2”, or
> >
> > — has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not
> >     reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an xvalue, class
> >     prvalue, or function lvalue of type “*cv3* T3”, where “*cv1* T1” is
> >     reference-compatible with “*cv3* T3” (see 13.3.1.6),
>
> *[..]* 
>   In the second case, if the reference is an rvalue reference and the second standard conversion sequence of the user-defined conversion
>   sequence includes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, the program is
>   ill-formed.

What is the *second* standard conversion sequence here? I thought there is a standard conversion sequence including all necessary standard conversions (user-defined and implicit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[over.ics.user]:

> A user-defined conversion **consists of an initial standard conversion sequence** followed by a user-defined conversion (12.3) followed by **a second standard conversion sequence**. […]
>   The second standard conversion sequence converts the result of the
>   user-defined conversion to the target type for the sequence.

E.g. for

```
struct A
{
    operator int();
};

void foo(short);

foo(A());
```

The second standard conversion sequence converts the `int` prvalue to the parameter of `foo`, that is, `short`. The first standard conversion sequence converts the `A` object to `A` (the implicit object parameter of `operator int`), which constitutes an identity conversion.
 For references, the rule quoted by you provides an example:

```
struct X {
    operator B();
    operator int&();
} x;

int&& rri2 = X(); // error: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to
                  // the result of operator int&
```

Here, `operator int&` is selected by overload resolution. The return value is an lvalue reference to `int`. For that to initialize the reference, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would be necessary, and that's precisely what the quote prevents: Lvalues shall not be bound to rvalue references.

Answer (score 4):

What the *standard conversion* term means is covered in the following clause of the C++ Standard:

> ### 4 Standard conversions `[conv]`
>
> 1. Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
>    — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion,
>      and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
>    — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and boolean conversions.
>
>    — Zero or one qualification conversion.
>
>    [ *Note:* A standard conversion sequence can be empty, i.e., it can consist of no conversions. — *end note* ]
>
> A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if necessary to convert it to a required
>   destination type.

In other words, the *standard conversion* is a set of built-in rules the compiler can apply when converting one type to another. Those built-in conversions include:

- No conversions
- Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
- Array-to-pointer conversion
- Function-to-pointer conversion
- Qualification conversions
- Integral promotions
- Floating point promotion
- Integral conversions
- Floating point conversions
- Floating-integral conversions
- Pointer conversions
- Pointer to member conversions
- Boolean conversions

The *standard conversion sequence* can appear **twice** during the *user-defined conversion sequence* - **either before and/or after** the *user-defined conversion*:

> #### § 13.3.3.1.2 User-defined conversion sequences `[over.ics.user]`
>
> 1. A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor (12.3.1), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type required by the argument of the constructor. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion function (12.3.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function.
> 2. The second standard conversion sequence converts the result of the user-defined conversion to the target type for the sequence. Since an implicit conversion sequence is an initialization, the special rules for initialization by user-defined conversion apply when selecting the best user-defined conversion for a user-defined conversion sequence (see 13.3.3 and 13.3.3.1).

Having that said, for the following conversion:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

- the compiler will search for the *conversion constructor* in `B` that can take an instance of `A` (*source type*) through some *initial standard conversion sequence* so that it could then perform that *user-defined conversion* through selected constructor, and then apply another *standard conversion* - **second standard conversion** - for converting the resultant type of the *user-defined conversion* to the *target type*;

  or:
- the compiler will search for the *conversion function* in `A` that is callable after some *initial standard conversion sequence* of the implicit context, that could then convert an instance of `A` to some type convertible through another *standard conversion* - the **second standard conversion** - to the *target type* `B`.

As a tangible example let's consider the below conversion:

```
struct A
{
    operator int() const;
};

A a;
bool b = a;
```

The compiler considers the following *user-defined conversion sequence*:

1. Initial standard conversion: *Qualification conversion* of `A*` to `const A*` to call `const`*-qualified* `operator int() const`.
2. User-defined conversion: conversion of `A` to `int`, through *user-defined conversion function*.
3. Second standard conversion: *Boolean conversion* of `int` to `bool`.

The case you are asking about can be split as follows:

```
struct A
{
    operator int&();
};

int&& b = A();
```

- The *source type* is `A`.
- The *target type* is `int&&`.
- The *user-defined conversion sequence* is the conversion of `A` to `int&&`.
- The *initial standard conversion sequence* is *No conversion* at all.
- The *user-defined conversion* is the conversion of `A` to `int&`.
- The *second standard conversion sequence* (converting the result of the *user-defined conversion* to the *target type*) that is a part of the overall *user-defined conversion sequence* would be here the *standard conversion* of `int&` to `int&&` - an *Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*. That conversion is considered since `int&` and `int&&` are *reference-compatible* types. According to the below statement §8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref]/p5:

> [...] if the reference is an rvalue reference and the second standard conversion sequence of the user-defined conversion sequence includes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, the program is ill-formed.

that conversion is not applicable in the overall *user-defined conversion sequence*.

Comment: *"In other words, the standard conversion is a set of built-in rules the compiler can apply when converting one type to another. Those built-in conversions include: [..]"* So does this mean if I have **explicit** pointer conversion or any explicit conversion from the list you provide above; does this mean that that  conversion is not considered **standard conversion sequance**?