# Are standard conversion sequences include explicit conversions?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I am just trying to understand what does the standard mean by "standard conversion sequences"; and I have ended up with that "standard conversion sequences" are "sequences of standard **implicit** conversions". But I think that's not true for some contexts; for instance, from [[expr.static.cast]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#7):

> [..] **A program is ill-formed if it uses static_­cast to perform the inverse of an ill-formed standard conversion sequence.**

```
struct B { };
struct D : private B { };
void f() {
  static_cast<D*>((B*)0);  // error: B is a private base of D
  // ..
}
```

And [General[conv.general]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#general-1) states:

> **Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning.**
> [..] A standard
> conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the
> following order:
>
> - [..]
> - (1.2) Zero or one conversion from the
>   following set: integral promotions, floating-point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating-point conversions, floating-integral
>   conversions, **pointer conversions**, pointer-to-member conversions, and
>   boolean conversions.
> - [..]

As I know, I think that a standard conversion sequence is only implicit conversions not including any explicit conversion. I mean the above conversion `(B*)0` is explicit pointer conversion, even though the standard said that this conversion is ill-formed ***standard conversion sequance***.

So if my thinking is true, why is this explicit cast expression `(B*)0` is said to be *standard conversion sequence* and it is an implicit conversion not explicit?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955983/18487620) on a some question:

> the standard conversion is a set of built-in rules the compiler can
> apply when converting one type to another. Those built-in conversions
> include:
>
> - No conversions
> - Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
> - Array-to-pointer conversion
> - Function-to-pointer conversion
> - Qualification conversions
> - Integral promotions
> - Floating point promotion
> - Integral conversions
> - Floating point conversions
> - Floating-integral conversions
> - Pointer conversions
> - Pointer to member conversions
> - Boolean conversions

Given the conversions above, if those conversions are performed explicitly, do they still said to be standard conversion sequences?

In general, Are conversions performed explicitly (including C++ cast operators) said to be standard conversion sequences?

Comment: I don't understand what connection you see between the `static_cast<D*>` and the `(B*)` cast. They are two independent casts, not related to each other. The former is ill-formed, because it would be the inverse of a `D* -> B*` implicit conversion that is forbidden by accessibility. The latter is just a conversion from a null pointer constant to `B*`, which is allowed for every pointer type, even implicitly.

Comment: @user17732522. What you're saying is not the point of my question.

Comment: @user17732522: _"The latter is just a conversion from a null pointer constant to B*"_. That's explicit pointer conversion. What I am asking for is: since this cast `(B*)0` is explicit conversion (not implicit) why it's said to be a standard conversion sequence?

Comment: I will edit the question itself to match what I intend.

Comment: Converting a null pointer constant (here: `0`) to `B*` is an implicit conversion and a standard conversion (pointer conversion). That you can use an explicit cast to do it as well doesn't affect that. "_even though the standard said that this conversion is ill-formed standard conversion sequance._": Where does it say that?

Comment: @user17732522: _"Where does it say that?"_ I have provided the quote in the question (expr.static.cast/7). But are you agree that implicit conversions are **only** those what the standard said "standard conversion sequence"?

Comment: Your quoted example is saying that `static_cast<D*>(E)` is ill-formed if `E` is an expression of type `B*`. The cast from `0` to `B*` is not relevant and there only to create a `B*` to use in the example.

Comment: I don't see why `(B*)0` requires an implicit conversion.  We're not asking the compiler to infer anything.

Comment: @user17732522: I don't know why you keep taking about something irreverent to the question "Are standard conversion sequences include explicit conversions?". From my example I am not asking why `(B*)0` ill-formed, instead why this explicit C_style cast is said to be "standard conversion sequence".

Comment: @user17732522 ... and I am thinking (maybe wrong) that "standard conversion sequences" are sequences of only standard **implicit** conversions, not explicit ones.

Comment: Explicit casts are not implicit conversions, but they may be using them effectively. For example `(B*)0` is defined as `static_cast<B*>(0)`, which is defined as direct-initialization of a prvalue of type `B*` from `0`, which uses a standard conversion sequence (i.e. implicit conversions) to convert `0` to `B*`. Yes only implicit conversions are part of any implicit conversion sequence (in particular any standard conversion sequence).

Comment: @user17732522 - I think you have come to what I want to ask, but there is something I cannot understand from you. You said that `(B*)0` which is equivalent to `static_cast<B*>(0)` which is at the end is "explicit casting" not "implicit conversion", so again the standard mentions that this "explicit casting" is ill-formed "standard conversion sequace (implicit conversion)" why???

Comment: `static_cast<B*>(0)` is an explicit cast, but it uses an implicit conversion to convert `0` to `B*`. As I mentioned earlier, your quotes from the standard are not saying that it is ill-formed.

Comment: @user17732522. Ohh thanks. The standard says *"A program is ill-formed if it uses static_­cast to perform the inverse of an ill-formed standard conversion sequence."* I have understood (thanks to you) that the sentence "ill-formed standard conversion sequence" doesn't refer to the cast expression `(B*)0`. Can you tell me what's the sentence "ill-formed standard conversion sequence" refers to here?

Comment: The cast `static_cast<D*>(...)` is ill-formed because the argument has type `B*`. This would be the inverse of the implicit conversion `D* -> B*` which is ill-formed according to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.ptr#3.sentence-2 because `B` is `private` base class of `D`. And so by the rule in your first quote the `static_cast` is also ill-formed.